# Macbook Pro with 10.7.5 hanging when closing screen

Tags: macbook-pro, performance

I have some problems on my Macbook.  Whenever I close the screen and I open it up again, the problem starts.  Sometimes I am able to login, but once I am inside, the computer freezers. Other times I am not even able to log in, because the login screen is frozen already.

I would like to know what are the possible causes of this and how could I potentially solve it.

I know the question might be a little bit vague, but that is basically what is happening.

EDIT:

```
Here is what I see in system.log at the time that I try to start again:

Dec  4 09:40:08 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1354610408 0
Dec  4 09:40:09 localhost com.apple.launchd[1]: *** launchd[1] has started up. ***
Dec  4 09:40:10 localhost com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.powerd): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
Dec  4 09:40:10 localhost com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.sandboxd): Unknown value for key POSIXSpawnType: Interactive
Dec  4 09:40:10 localhost fseventsd[24]: event logs in /.fseventsd out of sync with volume.  destroying old logs. (17609 1 51135)
Dec  4 09:40:10 localhost fseventsd[24]: log dir: /.fseventsd getting new uuid: F6EBD51C-B7F0-43E3-9213-78CB8EC03B64
Dec  4 09:40:11 localhost UserEventAgent[16]: starting CaptiveNetworkSupport as SystemEventAgent built Jun 25 2011 01:16:59
Dec  4 09:40:11 localhost UserEventAgent[16]: CaptiveNetworkSupport:CreateInterfaceWatchList:2788 WiFi Devices Found. :)
Dec  4 09:40:11 localhost UserEventAgent[16]: CaptiveNetworkSupport:CaptivePublishState:1211 en1 - PreProbe
Dec  4 09:40:11 localhost UserEventAgent[16]: CaptiveNetworkSupport:CaptiveSCRebuildCache:81 Failed to get service order
Dec  4 09:40:12: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  4 09:40:11 localhost UserEventAgent[16]: CaptiveNetworkSupport:CaptivePublishState:1211 en1 - PreProbe
Dec  4 09:40:11 localhost UserEventAgent[16]: CaptiveNetworkSupport:CaptiveSCRebuildCache:81 Failed to get service order
Dec  4 09:40:12: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  4 09:40:11 localhost UserEventAgent[16]: CertsKeychainMonitor: configuring
Dec  4 09:40:12 localhost UserEventAgent[16]: ServermgrdRegistration cannot load config data
Dec  4 09:40:12 localhost UserEventAgent[16]: get_backup_share_points no AFP
Dec  4 09:40:12 localhost airportd[30]: _processDLILEvent: en1 attached (down)
Dec  4 09:40:12 localhost UserEventAgent[16]: CaptiveNetworkSupport:CaptiveSCRebuildCache:81 Failed to get service order
Dec  4 09:40:12: --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  4 09:40:12 localhost UserEventAgent[16]: CaptiveNetworkSupport:CaptivePublishState:1211 en1 - PreProbe
Dec  4 09:40:13 localhost com.apple.pfctl[51]: No ALTQ support in kernel
Dec  4 09:40:13 localhost com.apple.pfctl[51]: ALTQ related functions disabled
Dec  4 09:40:13 localhost com.apple.ucupdate.plist[44]: ucupdate: Checked 1 update, no match found.
Dec  4 09:40:13 localhost launchdadd[25]: FAILURE: Could not send MIG reply: 0x10000003
Dec  4 09:40:13 localhost mDNSResponder[54]: mDNSResponder mDNSResponder-320.16 (Jul 19 2012 21:07:07) starting OSXVers 11
Dec  4 09:40:13 localhost com.apple.usbmuxd[43]: usbmuxd-296.3 on Jul 25 2012 at 00:28:37, running 64 bit
Dec  4 09:40:13 localhost com.apple.locationd[57]: ERROR,Time,376303213.157,Function,"void CLDaemonCore::startRun()",locationd was started after an unclean shutdown
Dec  4 09:40:13 localhost com.apple.locationd[57]: STACK,Time,376303213.157,1   locationd                           0x000000010fcaf254 locationd + 176724
Dec  4 09:40:13 localhost com.apple.locationd[57]: STACK,Time,376303213.157,2   locationd                           0x000000010fcb01c6 locationd + 180678
Dec  4 09:40:13 localhost com.apple.locationd[57]: STACK,Time,376303213.157,3   locationd                           0x000000010fce132c locationd + 381740
Dec  4 09:40:13 localhost com.apple.locationd[57]: STACK,Time,376303213.157,4   locationd                           0x000000010fc85fd8 locationd + 8152
Dec  4 09:40:13 localhost com.apple.locationd[57]: STACK,Time,376303213.157,5   ???
```

Comment: Is there anything "of interest" in the log files (`/var/log/...`) around the time of the freezing?

Comment: @patrix there are many files there. Which ones should I check?

Comment: system.log is always a good start

Comment: Edited my question with info in system.log

Comment: So, had you solve it?